# Dapper QueryAsync, return a list

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I have this task in C# with which i want to call a stored procedure in MySql using dapper.

```
public async Task<List<StatItemListViewModel>> GetTable()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("SampleDB")))
        {
            var results =await connection.QueryAsync<List<StatItemListViewModel>>("Call MainResult_Statistic(@sDate, @eDate)", new { sDate = "2018-11-01", eDate = "2018-11-30" });

            return results.FirstOrDefault();
        }            
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't return anything.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: *it doesn't return anything* you mean not even a empty list?

Comment: it returns an empty list i think, but the problem is not to the query cause it works in another scenario, for example:    `public List<StatItemListViewModel> GetTable()
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("SampleDB")))
            {
                var results =  connection.Query<StatItemListViewModel>("Call MainResult_Statistic(@sDate, @eDate)", new { sDate = "2018-11-01", eDate = "2018-11-30" }).ToList();

                return results;
            }            
        }` , in this case it returns the list

Comment: Are you sure you want to QueryAsync< **List** <Model>> and not QueryAsync<Model>? See https://dapper-tutorial.net/async#queryasync

Comment: @SirRufo it worked as you said, thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the issue like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StatItemListViewModel>> GetTable(string sDate, string eDate)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("SampleDB")))
    {
        var results = await connection.QueryAsync<StatItemListViewModel>("Call MainResult_Statistic(@sDate, @eDate)", 
            new { sDate, eDate });

        return results.ToList();
    }                  
}
```

The problem was that I could not convert generic.Ienumerable to generic.List.

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual async Task<T> QueryFirstAsync<T>(string strSql, object param)
{
    using (IDbConnection conn = Connection)
    {
        var res = await conn.QueryAsync<T>(strSql, param);
        return res.FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }
}
```